# Get yesterday's date and set time to 01:30:00

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of yesterday in `ISOString` and make sure time is showing `01:30:00`

I am trying the following code:

```js
const today = new Date()
const yesterday = new Date(today)

yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1)
yesterday.setHours(1,30,0)
console.log(yesterday)
x = today.toISOString()
y = yesterday.toISOString()
```

This is not giving the correct value in UST format.

For Example, if the date today is `2020-04-21T00:07:43.663Z` then I want to get `2020-04-20T01:30:00.000Z` as result in a variable.

Any Advice?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you really want. Yesterday at 1:30 am is not the same in Greenwich Mean Time *(UTC)*.

```js
const yesterday = new Date(Date.now()-86400000);
console.log(yesterday.toString());
yesterday.setHours(1, 30, 0, 0);
console.log(yesterday.toString());
console.log(yesterday.toISOString());
yesterday.setUTCHours(1, 30, 0, 0);
console.log('------------------------------');
console.log(yesterday.toISOString());
```

Comment: Yes, the key is that you are calling `setHours()`, which sets _local_ time, but then asking for _universal_ time via `toISOString()`. This solution doesn't use `setDate()`, but if it did, it would also need to be `setUTCDate()`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually following code did what I wanted to get
    const starttime = new Date(Date.now()-86400000);
    starttime.setUTCHours(0, 30, 0, 0);
    console.log(starttime.toISOString());

Comment: Well, that's not even 01:30.